# Script to open a webpage or at least hit a web api

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell, scripting

I need to write some kind of script that runs on a windows server that can be scheduled to run throughout a day to open a webpage to a specific address or at least hit an HTTP api it doesn't necessarily have to open a browser.

As a developer I've written web automation tests in the past for testing website functionality but this is outside my field of knowledge.

Any advice on even where is best to start would be great. I'm not sure if a batchfile, powershell script or any other type of scripting language is best.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest, native solution according to me.

using powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://your.url/path
```

Save as test.ps1 and just invoke it. Then schedule it using task scheduler.

Comment: Thats exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks :)